# Extract child's name from DatabaseReference in Google Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to extract the names (strings) of all the childs of mUsrRef.

```
DatabaseReference mUsrRef;

public void read_child() {
    mUsrRef = mUsersRef.child("user_name");
    // ...
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataSnapshot.getChildren()` for that:

```
public void read_child() {
  mUsrRef = mUsersRef.child("user_name");
  mUsrRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Log.i(TAG, childSnapshot.getKey());
      }
    }
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add a listener. For instance :

```
    mUsrRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ) {
                child.getKey();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.